# What makes a function parametric? Why are they used so much?

Tags: functions, parametrization

I believe I lack a great deal in my understanding of parameterisation.

The following vector-valued function $f(t) = (t\cos(t), t\sin(t))$ is said to be a parametric function but I don't understand why? Is it because it only has a one-dimensional input?

Secondly, why are parametric functions used so much in the multivariable world? What's the big deal? Can't we just use non-parametric functions?

Comment: Parametric functions are more flexible that plain xy functions. One reason: a given value of x can have multiple values of y. Another reason: it's possible to create parametric functions that have no easy-to-write `f(x) = ...` equivalent.

Comment: Your answer can be found on this wikipedia page - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation

Comment: @Jabeaumes I have never heard the phrase "parameteric function". I **have** heard of a parametric **equation** (or parametric equations) for a graph. As the fist comment notes, this is a more flexible way of describing a graph.

Comment: @Jabeaumes So for example, $(x,y) = (\cos(t),\sin(t))$ is a parametric equation describing a circle, whereas $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ is an implicit equation describing the same curve.